# Having trouble with my Dockerfile and setting correct working directory

Tags: docker, pytorch

This is my first Dockerfile and this is what I have so far.

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch


# install build utilities
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gcc make apt-transport-https ca-certificates build-essential

# check our python environment
RUN python3 --version
RUN pip3 --version

# set the working directory for containers
WORKDIR  /usr/src/toxic-content-monitoring

# Installing python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy all the files from the project’s root to the working directory
COPY src/ /src/
RUN ls -la /src/*

# Running Python Application
CMD ["python3", "/src/main.py"]
```

But when I am trying to run the docker image the files inside the data folder cannot be found.
Here is a picture of the my project structure.
[image]

Changed it to what was suggested and still getting an error.

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch

# install build utilities
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gcc make apt-transport-https ca-certificates build-essential

# check our python environment
RUN python3 --version
RUN pip3 --version

# set the working directory for containers
WORKDIR  /usr/src/toxic-content-monitoring

# Installing python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy all the files from the project’s root to the working directory
COPY src/ /src/
COPY data /data/
RUN ls -la /src/*

# Running Python Application
CMD ["python3", "/src/main.py"]
```

This is the error message.

```
docker run toxic-content-monitoring:0.1
wiki.en.vec: 6.60GB [10:05, 10.9MB/s]                                
  0%|          | 0/2519371 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Skipping token 2519370 with 1-dimensional vector ['300']; likely a header
100%|██████████| 2519371/2519371 [08:36<00:00, 4878.67it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    from preprocessor import normalize_comment, clean_text
  File "/src/preprocessor.py", line 42, in <module>
    word_file = open(link, "r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/identity_hateWordFile.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your Dockerfile is missing `COPY data/ /data/`  command in it.  You are only doing a copy of src folder and not data.  Please include `COPY data /data/` right after COPY src/ /src/ line in your Dockerfile and give it a try.

Comment: `nal vector ['300']; likely a header
100%|██████████| 2519371/2519371 [08:36<00:00, 4878.67it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    from preprocessor import normalize_comment, clean_text
  File "/src/preprocessor.py", line 42, in <module>
    word_file = open(link, "r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/identity_hateWordFile.txt'`

Comment: this new error seems to be because the python file is looking for a relative patch data    You can either move data folder within /src folder inside docker by changing the COPY line or pass absolute path to python file with /data/ because that's where the data directory is inside docker container filesystem.

Comment: Also you are better off mounting data as Docker's volume instead of copying